# How can I pass value from blade into controller in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I have this [form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDxKs.png) and I want to add a controller that receives the search query from the search form and echo it on the screen.

dashboard.blade file

```
 <form action="{{ route('Q') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <input type="text" name="query">

    <button type="submit"> search </button>
</form>
```

controller code :

```
class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    
    public function retrieveProducts(Request $request)
{
    $product = $request->input('query');
    dd($request->all());
}


}
```

I used this two routes :

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
});


Route::post('/', [ProductsController::class, 'retrieveProducts'])->name('Q');
```

The result : [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wk2cC.png).
expected result : [expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tu6mk.png)

Comment: Can you be more specific? Nothing is displayed, do you have an error message?

Can you also try in your controller to add `dd($request->all())` at the top of the action and edit your question with the result please?

Comment: @Jedupont done, I added the result and the expected result  at the end to make it clear.

Comment: You are not being clear. You want the search query shown on the blade view?  You can use `{{request()->query}}`